# retrieve Linq to SQL relational data in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, relational-database

I need to retrieve relational data through table:scan_LogEntry, I know how to retrieve all this data by running  multiple linq-sql queries, but im pretty sure that is not a very effective way of doing it. Im currently running this statement to retrieve a chunk of data from scan_LogEntry. But i want to show all the names rather than all the primary keys. I have been reading up on how to do this but the explanations i found are too complex for me to wrap my head around. Currently bringing up the data like this.

```
Public Class form_LogEntry_2
Private STleanappscontext As New STleanappsDataContext
Private scanbindsource As New BindingSource
Private Sub form_LogEntry_2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim begdt As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 8, 4)
    Dim enddt As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 8, 5)

    Dim logentryquery = From scan_LogEntries In STleanappscontext.scan_LogEntries
                        Where scan_LogEntries.tstStart >= begdt And scan_LogEntries.tstStart <= enddt
                        Select scan_LogEntries

    DataGridView1.DataSource = logentryquery
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
End Sub
End Class
```

The scan_LogEntries table holds many-to-one relationships with 4 other tables through the following columns (userCode, projectCode, actionCode, departmentCode) is there a simple way for me to retrieve this data without cycling through my list 4 times and looking up each primary key individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The Join statement to link the other tables

```
Dim logentryquery = From scan_LogEntries In STleanappscontext.scan_LogEntries
                            Join user In Usertable
                            On user.id Equals scan_LogEntries.usercode
                        Where scan_LogEntries.tstStart >= begdt And scan_LogEntries.tstStart <= enddt
                        Select scan_LogEntries, user.name
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks man, that is exactly what I was looking for, a simple example that I can understand and reproduce :)